# Maven Plugin Dependency : class not found

Tags: java, maven, maven-2, cxf

I am trying to add the "cxf-java2ws-plugin" of Apache CXF to my pom.xml file
When executing default goal (java2ws) in the "process-classes" phase, I get a class not found exception :

> A required class was missing while executing
>   org.apache.cxf:cxf-java2ws-plugin:3.1.11:java2ws:
>   org/apache/cxf/helpers/CastUtil

The weird thing is that I have the right dependency, and I can see the JAR (cxf-core-3.1.11.jar) that has the required class file in the realm urls. I checked insinde the JAR, the class file is there. (see urls[4] below)

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.cxf:cxf-java2ws-plugin:3.1.11:java2ws (default) on project MasterCardServiceStub: Execution default of goal org.apache.cxf:cxf-java2ws-plugin:3.1.11:java2ws failed: A required class was missing while executing org.apache.cxf:cxf-java2ws-plugin:3.1.11:java2ws: org/apache/cxf/helpers/CastUtils
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] realm =    plugin>org.apache.cxf:cxf-java2ws-plugin:3.1.11
[ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
[ERROR] urls[0] = file:/C:/SBIv2/m2/repository/org/apache/cxf/cxf-java2ws-plugin/3.1.11/cxf-java2ws-plugin-3.1.11.jar
[ERROR] urls[1] = file:/C:/SBIv2/m2/repository/org/apache/cxf/cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws/3.1.11/cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws-3.1.11.jar
[ERROR] urls[2] = file:/C:/SBIv2/m2/repository/xml-resolver/xml-resolver/1.2/xml-resolver-1.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[3] = file:/C:/SBIv2/m2/repository/org/ow2/asm/asm/5.0.4/asm-5.0.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[4] = file:/C:/SBIv2/m2/repository/org/apache/cxf/cxf-core/3.1.11/cxf-core-3.1.11.jar
[ERROR] urls[5] = file:/C:/SBIv2/m2/repository/org/codehaus/woodstox/woodstox-core-asl/4.4.1/woodstox-core-asl-4.4.1.jar
...
```

Here's my "most simple" plugin config

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-java2ws-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.11</version>


            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.11</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-simple</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.11</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>


            <executions>
                <execution>

                    <!-- bind this plugin goal to the specific maven phase -->
                    <phase>process-classes</phase>
                    <configuration>

                        <className>org.apache.hello_world.Greeter</className>
                        <genWsdl>true</genWsdl>
                        <verbose>true</verbose>
                    </configuration>
                    <!-- the plugin specific goal -->
                    <goals>
                        <goal>java2ws</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>

        </plugin>
```

Comment: Are you using Maven 2? Or Maven 3 ? Why have added dependencies to the plugin ? Is that mentioned in the documentation ?

Comment: I copied the config from CXF doc. That's why I have the dependencies. Using maven 3.3.9, but tried it with 3.5.0, hoping it could fix the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caused by corrupted JAR in local repo

Comment: I had a similar problem. I went about removing local repository and do mvn clean package. Worked.

Answer (score 0):

try to use below version of `<artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-simple</artifactId>` from 3.1.11. and update maven project

Comment: below version... from 3.1.11?below what? You mean change version to newer, older?